# Regex for re.findall the phone numbers in websites don´t find phone numbers with brackets

Tags: python, regex, csv

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a mejorar mi expresión regular para encontrar todos los números de teléfono? No reconoce números de teléfono con paréntesis como (000) 0000 0000.
¡Gracias!

Someone could help me to improve my regex for find all the phone numbers? It does not recognize phone numbers with parentheses as (000) 0000 0000.
Thank you!

```
   for line in url_file:
        try:
            u = line.strip()
            print(u)
            url = u
            response = requests.get(u)
            data = response.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')  
            dupl = set()

            phone = re.findall(r'\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}', data, re.MULTILINE)

            phn_1 = []

            if len(phone) == 0:
                print ("No phone number found.")
            else:
                count = 1
                for item in phone:
                    phn_1.append(item)
                    count += 1
                print (set(phn_1))   
                phn = (set(phn_1))
```

Comment: Translate your question please. This site is in Spanish

Comment: Ya lo escribí en español.

Answer (score 0):

Está expresión regular te puede servir:

```
r'\b\(?\d{3}\)? \d{3} \d{4}
```

El elemento `\b` calza con un comienzo de palabra. Lo pusimos ahí para asegurar que estamos contando dígitos desde el comienzo de la palabra, no desde el medio.

Luego tenemos `\(?` y `\)?` que reconocen cero o un paréntesis. Ojo: también reconoce paréntesis mal balanceados. Habría que revisar explicitamente este factor.

También reemplace los `.` por espacios en la expresión. Los `.` calzan con cualquier cosa, incluyendo dígitos.

#### Demo

```
import re

tests = [
    "(000) 000 0000",
    "000 000 0000",
    "(000 000 0000",
    "000) 000 0000",
    "1234 000 0000",
    "1234000 0000",
    "000 (000) 0000"]

for data in tests:
    phone = re.findall(r'\b\(?\d{3}\)? \d{3} \d{4}', data)
    print(data, phone)
```

produce:

```
(000) 000 0000 ['000) 000 0000']
000 000 0000 ['000 000 0000']
(000 000 0000 ['000 000 0000']
000) 000 0000 ['000) 000 0000']
1234 000 0000 []
1234000 0000 ['1234000 0000']
000 (000) 0000 []

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Pero esto es lo que obtengo en la terminal: No phone number found.

Comment: @user19233490 No tengo acceso a tus datos ...

Comment: http://www.arcticmedicalcenter.com por ejemplo, esta website.

Comment: https://www.sleepcentersofalaska.com/ y este es un ejemplo de website con varios teléfonos, uno con paréntesis.